# In ConstraintLayout, how to align to the baseline of 2nd line?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In `ConstraintLayout`, if we want to align a `TextView`, to another `TextView`'s baseline, we can simply apply `layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf`

### Align to the baseline of 1st line

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:background="#FFEB3B"
        android:text="Wed, Nov 11"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        android:textColor="?attr/primaryTextColor"

        android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:background="#CDDC39"
        android:text="This is text with 1 line"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"

        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"

        android:textColor="?attr/secondaryTextColor"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/tiny_title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:breakStrategy="simple"
        
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/title_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/title_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/title_text_view" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

But, what if, there is 2 lines in the `TextView`, and we want to align to the baseline of 2nd line?

### How can we align to the baseline of 2nd line

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:background="#FFEB3B"
        android:text="Wed, Nov 11"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        android:textColor="?attr/primaryTextColor"

        android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:background="#CDDC39"
        android:text="This is text with 1 line"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"

        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"

        android:textColor="?attr/secondaryTextColor"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/tiny_title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:breakStrategy="simple"
        
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/title_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/title_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/title_text_view" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

As you can see in the above screenshot, `app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf` is always align to the baseline of 1st line. Is there a way, for us to align to the baseline of 2nd line?

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFEB3B"
            android:text="Wed, Nov 11"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"

            android:textSize="20sp"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tiny_title_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"

            android:background="#CDDC39"

            android:breakStrategy="simple"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:text="This is text with 1 line and this is line 2"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
            android:textSize="20sp"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/title_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/title_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Simply Go For :** [image]

Comment: the code is modified already. you can copy paste and run to see the changes!